# MBP: How to change the touchbar icons for when it's LOCKED?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, touch-bar

When my machine is locked- I only get some media icons (stop/play, volume) but I really would love to have the FWD (skip this stupid song) icon, etc.

I can't seem to find a way to edit the icons that show when the machine is locked.

I'm mainly using Amazon Music, if it matters.

Google has been trash for help in this regard too.

Thanks

Comment: what operating system are you running

Comment: mac os, catalina